# How do we copy a custom table style from Word to Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word-2007, table-styles

We're using Word 2007 and Outlook 2007. We've got a corporate table style defined in Word and set as the default.

How do we make that table style available in Outlook mail messages? I can't see any organise/export/manage styles option over there. I can see that we can define a **New Table Style** but really don't want to recreate it from scratch.

Comment: You're most likely going to need to create a macro in excel and transfer it to outlook. The references will be different, so it will take some tweaking. A simpler option would be to copy and paste the table from excel into outlook new message and work there, or work the table in excel and copy and paste it to outlook

Comment: Excel? It's Outlook & Word we're using

Comment: Pardon my confusion! Just replace the "excels" with "word". My suggestion is still macro

Comment: right, thanks, i'll give it a try. i was just checking you didn't mean we had to go _via Excel_ to do it!

Comment: No, my head was in excel as it always is and we can just pretend they are typos >.>